# Problem in opening files with filenames in Devanagari

Tags: init-file, filenames, utf-8

I am using Emacs 28.2 on Trisquel 11.

I have installed it using 'guix package manager'. When I am trying to open a file named in Devanagari characters it opens as blank file and the file name on mode bar appears as garbage. (Please see the image.

[image]

On the other hand, when I open the same file using the mini buffer, it opens correctly as can be seen in image bellow.

[image]

I have also tried adding following in my init file.

```
(set-language-environment "UTF-8")
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: There is also a variable `default-file-name-coding-system`, try to set it with the actual conding for file name (utf-8 may not always be).